# synchronize scrolling of N number of jtables in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have a requirement of having N number of tables arranged in a grid pane side by side provided height of the scrollpanes of all the jtables remains same. Now i want to synchronize scroll of all the jtables means if i scroll the first jtable then rest of the jtables should scroll automatically by the same amount.

Anyone has any idea about this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try sharing the model of the scrollbar. Something like:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(...);
BoundedRangeModel model scrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel();
scrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel( model );
```

Comment: camickr - how to unshare model of all n tables after share the model. Actually i have 1 synchronize checkbox in my screen. on click of checkbox i have to synchronize n number of table and and on uncheck of checkbox i have to unshare model of all the n tables. thats my question. do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Create and add an new BoundedRangeModel to the scrollbar.

Comment: camickr - BoundedRangeModel is an interface. How can i create the object of BoundedRangeModel and add it into scrollbar ?

Comment: Read the API and find a class that implements the interface. All models have a default implementation.

Comment: I found the solution by adding new scrollbars: scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL));

Answer (score 0):

Get the scrollbars of your scrollpanes (`getHorizontalScrollBar()` or `getVerticalScrollBar()`). Then catch events from these. When an event occurs, modify the viewports (`getViewport()`) associated to the scrollpanes with `setViewPosition()` (from `getViewPosition()`).